# How to combine 2 Json objects into a single Json object using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, performance, mapreduce

I have 3 JSON objects as defined below:

```
 const totalData = [{ Hostname: "abc123", name: "CName-A", Status: "PASS", Heading: "Not Applicable" },
            { Hostname: "abc123", name: "CName-B", Status: "FAIL", Heading: "Not Applicable" },
            { Hostname: "abc235", name: "CName-C", Status: "FAIL", Heading: "Not Applicable" },
            { Hostname: "abc235", name: "CName-D", Status: "FAIL", Heading: "Not Applicable" }];

const otherTotalData = [{ Hostname: "abc123", name: "QName-A", Status: "PASS", Heading: "HeadingQA" },
            { Hostname: "abc123", name: "QName-B", Status: "FAIL", Heading: "HeadingQB" },
            { Hostname: "abc235", name: "QName-C", Status: "FAIL", Heading: "Not Applicable" },
            { Hostname: "abc235", name: "QName-D", Status: "FAIL", Heading: "Not Applicable" }];

const newTotalData = [{ Hostname: "abc123", name: "TName-A", Status: "PASS", Heading: "HeadingTA" },
            { Hostname: "abc123", name: "TName-B", Status: "FAIL", Heading: "HeadingTB" },
            { Hostname: "abc235", name: "TName-C", Status: "FAIL", Heading: "Not Applicable" },
            { Hostname: "abc235", name: "TName-D", Status: "FAIL", Heading: "Not Applicable" }];
```

I have a function which uses `array reduce` method:

```
function createArray(totalData) {
const keyValues = ["Status", "Heading"],
    result = Object.values(totalData.reduce((res, { Hostname, name, ...o }) => {
        res[Hostname] = res[Hostname] || { Hostname };
        keyValues.forEach(k => res[Hostname][name + k] = o[k]);
        return res;
    }, {}));
}
```

Now, I am calling the two functions:

```
const Res1 = createArray(totalData);

const Res2 = createArray(otherTotalData);

const Res3 = createArray(newTotalData);
```

Here Res1 has the output:

```
[
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "CName-AStatus": "PASS",
    "CName-BStatus": "FAIL"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc235",
    "CName-CStatus": "FAIL",
    "CName-DStatus": "FAIL"
    }
]
```

And, Res2 has the output:

```
[
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "QName-AStatus": "PASS",
    "QName-BStatus": "FAIL"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc235",
    "QName-CStatus": "FAIL",
    "QName-DStatus": "FAIL"
    }
]
```

And, Res3 has the output:

```
[
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "TName-AStatus": "PASS",
    "TName-BStatus": "FAIL"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc235",
    "TName-CStatus": "FAIL",
    "TName-DStatus": "FAIL"
    }
]
```

I want to combine Res1, Res2 and Res3 such that the final Json object looks as following:

```
[
    {
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "CName-AStatus": "PASS",
    "CName-BStatus": "FAIL",
    "QName-AStatus": "PASS",
    "QName-BStatus": "FAIL",
    "TName-AStatus": "PASS",
    "TName-BStatus": "FAIL"
    },
    {
    "Hostname": "abc235",
    "CName-CStatus": "FAIL",
    "CName-DStatus": "FAIL",
    "QName-CStatus": "FAIL",
    "QName-DStatus": "FAIL",
    "TName-CStatus": "FAIL",
    "TName-DStatus": "FAIL"
    }
]
```

How can I combine `Res1` `Res2` and `Res3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just map over one array and use index to get respective value from another array and merge values

```js
let res1 = [{"Hostname": "abc123","CName-AStatus": "PASS","CName-BStatus": "FAIL"},{"Hostname": "abc235","CName-CStatus": "FAIL","CName-DStatus": "FAIL"}]
let res2 = [{"Hostname": "abc123","QName-AStatus": "PASS","QName-BStatus": "FAIL"},{"Hostname": "abc235","QName-CStatus": "FAIL","QName-DStatus": "FAIL"}]

let final = res1.map((inp, index) => {
  return { ...inp,
    ...res2[index]
  }
})

console.log(final)
```

P.S:-  This considers the arrays are sorted in same order and always a respective value is present in other array. ( considering your given example data ). If that is not the case then we just need to find the respective value from other array based on some property and the merge.

```js
let res1 = [{"Hostname": "abc123","CName-AStatus": "PASS","CName-BStatus": "FAIL"},{"Hostname": "abc235","CName-CStatus": "FAIL","CName-DStatus": "FAIL"}]
let res2 = [{"Hostname": "abc235","QName-CStatus": "FAIL","QName-DStatus": "FAIL"},{"Hostname": "abc123","QName-AStatus": "PASS","QName-BStatus": "FAIL"}]


let final = [...res1,...res2].reduce((op,inp)=>{
  let key = inp.Hostname
  if(op.has(key)){
    op.set(key, {...op.get(key), ...inp} )
  } else{
    op.set(key, inp)
  }
  return op
}, new Map())

console.log([...final.values()])
```

Comment: Actually in my final requirement, I have 3 response objects instead of 2. I want to combine `res1`, `res2`and `res3`. Can you please update your answer accordingly?. I have updated my question.

Comment: @meallhour just use the second one `[...res1, ...res2, ...res3]` and you're good to go

Comment: Also you can extend the first one as well, just need to update the return value `{... inp, ...res2[index], ...res3[index] }`

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can search the other array with shared property: "Hostname" and use `Object.assign` to combine two objects together.

```js
const res1 = [{
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "CName-AStatus": "PASS",
    "CName-BStatus": "FAIL"
  },
  {
    "Hostname": "abc235",
    "CName-CStatus": "FAIL",
    "CName-DStatus": "FAIL"
  }
];

const res2 = [{
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "QName-AStatus": "PASS",
    "QName-BStatus": "FAIL"
  },
  {
    "Hostname": "abc235",
    "QName-CStatus": "FAIL",
    "QName-DStatus": "FAIL"
  }
];

const res3 = [{
    "Hostname": "abc123",
    "TName-AStatus": "PASS",
    "TName-BStatus": "FAIL"
  },
  {
    "Hostname": "abc235",
    "TName-CStatus": "FAIL",
    "TName-DStatus": "FAIL"
  }
];

function mergeAll(key, ...args) {
  const arr = Array.from(args);
  const first = arr[0];
  const rest = arr.slice(1);

  return first.map(r => Object.assign({}, r, ...rest.map(q => q.find(t => t[key] === r[key]))));
}

const result = mergeAll('Hostname', res1, res2, res3);
console.log(result);
```

**Edit:** As Op mentioned in the comments there are 3 results to merge so I made a generalized method for any number of results.

Comment: Actually in my final requirement, I have 3 response objects instead of 2. I want to combine `res1`, `res2`and `res3`. Can you please update your answer accordingly?. I have updated my question.